# list not being sorted by nums1 = sorted(nums1) but getting sorted by nums1[:] = sorted(nums1)

Tags: python, data-structures

I am trying to solve the problem of merging sorted arrays in-place, without using an extra array

```
nums1[:] = nums1[:m]
nums1[:] = nums1 + nums2
nums1[:] = sorted(nums1)
```

however the above solution doesn't work with nums1 instead of nums1[:] on the LHS.
What does nums1[:] mean here? Why doesn't the following code work:

```
nums1[:] = nums1[:m]
nums1 = nums1 + nums2
nums1 = sorted(nums1)
```

here nums1 and nums2 are two sorted arrays that have to be merged.

Example:

```
Input:
nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0], m = 3
nums2 = [2,5,6],       n = 3

Output: [1,2,2,3,5,6]
```

Comment: nums1[:] means you're slicing the list from start to end. Could you specify what doesn't work? Because I tried to run your code and seemed to do the job perfectly fine to me: [check it out.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoMS8lP5crrzS32FDBViEawtcDUZl5JRoGOgqGBgaaCmn5RQqZCpl5IPXpqRpGBpqxYD1GWPXg1JJra2jKVVAEUgW2UUcBbIgm3H4wHW2VG4usCiatDZE3wiZnq1AM9E5qCkwUWcn//wA)

Comment: the first code snippet works but the second one does not

Comment: These two snippets should be practically equivalent, so please [edit] to clarify what the problem is. Also include the definitions of `nums1` and `nums2`. See [mre] for reference.

Comment: well, the second snippet is not working. that is what my doubt is in the first place, that despite the fact that they should be equivalent, the first code snippet works in the IDE while the other one does not. nums1 and nums2 are two sorted arrays that have to be merged.

Comment: So, what's the output of the second snippet for you?

Comment: for inputs nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0] and nums2 = [2,5,6] instead of giving the correct result [1,2,2,3,5,6] it gives a result of [1,2,3,0,0,0]

Comment: I've tried running both snippets but they produce the same `nums1` list out. Please make sure you've posted a [mre]. (I tried Python 2.7, 3.5, and 3.6.)